# How to get parameters of a method using reflection api

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection, interceptor

I have a method which is intercepted. I have an annotation placed on one of the parameters passed to the method. I want to know which parameter is annotated with that particular annotation and want to get its value.

```
@AccessControlled
public String getEmployees(@EmployeeId String id, String type) {
}
```

From the `InvocationContext` I got the method. When I call `context.getParameters()` I get an array of values which were passed to that method.

I don't see any method called `getParameters()` on method object.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think I got it. I have to use the index]

Comment: If you have got it, please close the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want `ctx.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations()`, if `ctx` is your `InvocationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `java.lang.reflect.Method` instance `m`, you
can check its annotations for `AccessControlled` with this code.

```
        Annotation[] anns = m.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation ann : anns){
            Class clazz = ann.annotationType();
            if (clazz == AccessControlled.class){
                // do something here
            }
        }
```

I assume you know how to get to the `m` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < parameterAnnotations.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < parameterAnnotations[i].length; j++) {
        if (parameterAnnotations[i][j].annotationType() == EmployeeId.class) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index > -1) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(context.getParameters()[index]);
```